# Need help getting resolveRouteBinding working in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, binding, routes, resolve

I'm having difficulty getting resolveRouteBinding on my model to work in Laravel 8.10.0

```
    $ php artisan --version
    Laravel Framework 8.10.0
```

I've followed the docs over at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding to add my own resolveRouteBinding method but it doesn't seem to work when I call the route.  My model is as follows:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Post extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;

        /**
         * Get the user that owns the post.
         */
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $value
         * @param  string|null  $field
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
         */
        public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
        {
            // return $this->find(1)->firstOrFail();
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

Here is my PostController:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Post;

    class PostController extends Controller
    {
        public function view(Post $post) {
            dd($post);
        }
    }
```

And, my route in web.php:

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

    Route::get('/post/{item_id}', [PostController::class, 'view']);
```

When I try to load this route in a browser, I see the dump of a newly created Post object.  It didn't seem to execute the abort(404) and additional model->find logic doesn't work.  Calling the resolveRouteBinding method directly from artisan tinker works as expected, so, I know it the method works.

```
    $ php artisan tinker
    Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.4.10 — cli) by Justin Hileman
    >>> use App\Models\Post;
    >>> $post = new Post();
    => App\Models\Post {#3552}
    >>> $post->resolveRouteBinding(1, null);
    Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception/NotFoundHttpException
    >>> quit
    Exit:  Goodbye
```

Can anyone tell what I'm missing?  I know this worked in Laravel 5.8.  I'm not sure about interim versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to match the type-hinted parameter in your method to the same name as the route parameter if you want Implicit Route Model Binding to take place:

```
Route::get('/post/{post}', [PostController::class, 'view']);

public function view(Post $post)
```

The route parameter named `post`, `{post}`, matches the method parameter named `post`, `$post`.

Comment: Thank you!  This was the detail I was missing.